# Apply Access Ajax API permission to allow Add new organization option to public autocomplete for current employer, still not works

Tags: civievent, civicontribute, civimember, contacts, custom-fields

Civicrm-4.7. Apply Access Ajax API permission to allow Add new organization option to public autocomplete(1.4 v) for current employer field, but still not works!.[image]

Comment: Please add some more details what you are trying to archive and what you have already tried. What kind of form are you using? A CiviCRM profile? In a contribution page? Or maybe a webform?

Comment: Added ext. public autocomplete v 1.4 for current employer. Now anonymous user get list of org. name but its added only one org name. Needed multiple org name for anon user. Already set all the permission but its not working to current employer add new org name. Need Help!!!

Answer (score 0):

Pls check the following permission is provided to users:

CiviCRM: access AJAX API 
Allow API access even if Access CiviCRM is not granted